# can bluetooth low energy be used like nfc - say printed to an ID badge?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using my iPhone to scan in a complex 2D barcode. Problem is, the iPhone camera doesn't do so well at very close distances (less than 3 inches).

I was wondering if there were a way I could affix a Bluetooth low energy "sticker" to a piece of paper. The idea being instead of using the camera to scan a 2D barcode, I could just put my iPhone near the paper and "scan" it.

I'm extremely new to Bluetooth tech, so it's quite possible that what I'm asking for is completely ridiculous. Please forgive me, if that is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike NFC, Bluetooth Low-Energy devices need a power source, so it's imposible to just "print" them. They need a BLE chip and a battery to operate. So while you could use BLE same way you use NFC (proximity-based actions), you won't be able to do it with just a sticker.

Answer (score -1):

Register at bluetooth sig for manufactorer id. Then put manufacturer id in advertisement package 0xff with id (16 bit) followed by the data. You must be sure your length is correct or iOS can't decode it.

Answer (score -1):

For NFC, your scanner must be pretty close to the tag. But BLE devices work within several tens of meters without any problem. This is like an active RFID chip.

Of course, you need a power source for it. But if you print this BLE tag to a piece of expensive equipment, the cost of the tag and the battery is not a problem. You can use a button cell battery to power the BLE tag up. Let is broadcast/advertise some info once a second. Of course, you have to add some security mechanism if you want to be away from any replay attacks.